# How have cameras, radios, and related electronics improved since Apollo?

Tags: technology

When you look at Apollo-era hardware (still and movie cameras, radio gear, etc.) much of it appears to be bulky and probably quite heavy by modern standards, surprising when you consider how much weight was a concern for just getting to the Moon.

For example:

- Still cameras recording on 70mm film preloaded into magazines
- Bulky video cameras with large (100mm or so) objective lenses offering maybe 100 line resolution
- Thick cables with large connectors
- Silver-zinc batteries (as used in the lunar rover)

By contrast, modern commercial/consumer technology offers:

- All-digital still cameras offering tens of megapixel resolution in a package you can fit in a pocket with memory cards the size of a fingernail capable of holding thousands of high-resolution images
- High-definition video cameras, again, small enough to fit in a pocket, with objective lenses a fraction the size of a dime
- USB
- Lithium batteries

Of course, space is a harsh environment where consumer technology may not fare very well. There is radiation which can have significant effect on high density chips (processors, memory, image sensors); the vacuum of space can present problems for heat dissipation, and an astronaut has limited dexterity in a space suit, so can manipulate things only so small.

But...

If an Apollo-style lunar mission were mounted today, how much benefit would be brought by 50 years of technological advancement? To what extent does the space environment limit the reductions in size and weight we enjoy in the consumer environment?

For example:

The current state of the art for semiconductors supplying the commercial/consumer market is around 14nm; I assume this is well below the limit for radiation-hard devices, but what is that limit?

What would a state-of-the-art spaceworthy still camera look like - one of equal performance to the Apollo era Hasselblad? How big/heavy would it be?

What would a state-of-the-art spaceworthy video camera look like - one able to perform as well as that used on Apollo 15-17 (presumably of equal light performance but superior resolution)? How big/heavy would it be? How big would the objective lens be?

Comment: This question is a bit broad because, except for the rockets themselves, just about everything in aerospace has improved by multiple orders of magnitude since the Apollo days.

Comment: @DavidHammen I know there have been improvements, and to some extent, the 60s space race either initiated or accelerated many of them, but we enjoy smaller/cheaper/faster to a greater degree in our everyday technology than can be used in space because of the environment; I wanted to get a sense of how much.

Comment: I would think the guidance computer is the biggest potential weight saving - several cubic feet of system would now fit on the tiniest silicon

Comment: I suspect that a crewed moon mission designed today would include 2kg of new features for every 1kg saved by 50 years of technical advancement.

Comment: +infinity to that comment @RussellBorogove

Comment: @RussellBorogove - Perhaps; Parkinson's law is universal. But I doubt we would only send two to the surface or that we would only stay for a few days. This ups the ante on consumables. I suspect we will have to make do with significantly less mass for avionics and scientific equipment than was allotted for Apollo.

Comment: Maybe I should refocus the question a bit. I'm really interested in things like: does a film camera have any advantages over digital for mission science or general documentation and why? How much smaller/lighter would a suitable digital camera be? How much smaller/lighter would a video camera be for equivalent use as those used on the Moon? As small and light as a cellphone camera or less so, and why?

Comment: surprising only with 50 years of hindsight, Apollo equipment was state-of-the-art at the time.

Comment: My dad was on the team responsible for calculating the lunar terrain from the camera images.  There were some interesting things they did to try to deal with the limitations of using film camera.  Given that, they were REALLY NICE cameras.  He brought one home once to show me.